# SCM Manager returning 404 error when I try to restart scm from console

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, scmmanager

Goodevening Stackoverflow,

Today I upgraded scm from version 1.60 to 2.30 only that it returns a 404 error from Google console (the browser just keeps loading until the request times out).

running `journalctl -u scm-server` returning the following error:

```
Exception in thread "ScmEventBus-1-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna6511840250923886855.tmp: /tmp/jna6511840250923886855.tmp: failed to map segment from shared object`
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)`
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:810)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1088)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1018)
at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:988)
at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:195)
at com.sun.akuma.CLibrary.<clinit>(CLibrary.java:89)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.resolvePID(JavaVMArguments.java:128)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.ofLinux(JavaVMArguments.java:116)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.of(JavaVMArguments.java:104)
at com.sun.akuma.JavaVMArguments.current(JavaVMArguments.java:92)
at sonia.scm.lifecycle.PosixRestartStrategy.restart(PosixRestartStrategy.java:57)
at sonia.scm.lifecycle.PosixRestartStrategy.executeRestart(PosixRestartStrategy.java:47)
at sonia.scm.lifecycle.RestartStrategy.restart(RestartStrategy.java:67)
at sonia.scm.lifecycle.BootstrapContextFilter.handleRestartEvent(BootstrapContextFilter.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.github.legman.InvocationContext.invoke(InvocationContext.java:108)
at com.github.legman.InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContext.java:101)
at com.github.legman.micrometer.MicrometerInvocationInterceptor.invoke(MicrometerInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at com.github.legman.InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContext.java:99)
at com.github.legman.EventHandler.handleEvent(EventHandler.java:103)
at com.github.legman.SynchronizedEventHandler.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventHandler.java:52)
at com.github.legman.EventBus.dispatchSynchronous(EventBus.java:452)
at com.github.legman.EventBus.lambda$dispatch$1(EventBus.java:444)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.doRun(SubjectRunnable.java:120)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectRunnable.run(SubjectRunnable.java:108)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)`*
```

From google chrome console I get the following error:

```
GET http://serverip/scm/api/v2/ 404 (Not Found) ApiClient.request @ apiclient.ts?718f:307
```

If I force restart from the server with `service scm-server restart`, scm manager returns up and running, and with the plugin installed.

Now it seems like the browser is finding it difficult to successfully restart SCM service even if in scm-manager.log I can see the jvm service was restarted.

I also checked the apache log error_log and found an error as follows:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 32822] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[proxy_http:error] [pid 32822] [client 10.12.173.165:62193] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
[proxy:error] [pid 32821] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
```

The thing is with version 1.60 I never got any of these errors, the reverse proxy settings in httpd.conf works until this restart from console activity.

I really apologise for the long story, I am only trying to make it comprehensive as much as possibile.

Thanks to anyone willing to help a brother.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because your scm-manager restart accesses the `tmp` folder where it has no right to execute. This issue with jna is known by the SCM-Manager team and will be fixed soon.

As workaround try: After installation, run `chmod -R 775 scm` and scm should be able to restart service from browser

Comment: Thank Eduard. 

This might be coming in late but the solution was both chown to scm user and also chmod.

The file permission differs between version 1.60 and version 2.3